# How can I change the value of a variable with a void method?

Tags: android, void, abbreviation

Thank you for answering. 
I'm trying to change the value of a variable with a void method.

```
public void function(int x){
    x=x*x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
public void main(String args){
    int p=5;
    System.out.println(p);    //The output would be 5.
    function(p);             //The output would be 25.
    System.out.println(p);    //The output would be 5, again.
}
```

What can I do in order to change the value of "p" by calling the method?

Comment: We're not here to write your code. This question is off-topic here since it's too localized.

Comment: Oh, my fault! Excuse me man, I'm not asking you to write my code, I just need an advice or something that can guide me. Maybe you misunderstood my question since the english is not my native language.

Comment: I understood you %100 correctly. But your question is not suitable on StackOverflow and will probably be closed due to the localization. This question isn't helpful for future readers, only to you. Which is why it is off-topic.

Comment: Well, you're right with that. I'm going to try to get more information by researching and make the question more general, would it be more proper? Thank you for the information about the purpose of StackOverflow, I didn't know it. Just saw that some people asked questions and the community answered them.

Comment: That's alright! We all made mistakes. If you fix your question and notify I'll be sure to remove the downvote and possibly invert it :)

Comment: I've already edited it. Done! Is it proper now?